# Verify that $\mathbb R$ is an ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, field-theory

Hi i need help with the following question below:

A field F (of numbers) is said to be ordered if there is a subset P ⊂ F with the following
properties:

(1) If a, b ∈ P, then a + b ∈ P and a · b ∈ P.

(2) If a ∈ F, then precisely one of the following holds:
a ∈ P, or
−a ∈ P, or
a = 0.

Question:

1. Verify that R is ordered.
2. Prove that there is no choice of P ⊂ C that makes C ordered.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the properties of the reals that we all know and love, or do you need to go back to your definition of the reals?  If the second, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

For the real numbers, the set, P, is the set of positive real numbers.

Suppose there exist a subset, P, of the complex numbers that satisfies those.  Either i is in that set or not.

a) Suppose i is in P.  Then, by the first condition, (i)(i)= -1 is in the set and then (-1)(i)= -i is in the set.  But that contradicts the second condition, that one and **only one** of "$x\in P$ or $-x\in P$ or $x= 0" s true.

b) Suppose i is not in the set.  Then -i is in the set so (-i)(-i)= -1 is in the set and then (-1)(-i)= i is in the set.  That is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to try to figure out what $P\subset \mathbb R$ is we can start by figuring out whether $1\in P$ or $1 \not \in P$.  If $1\in P$ then $1\cdot 1 = 1$ and $1+1=2$ are both in $P$ and ... we don't have any immediate contradiction. But if $1 \not \in P$ then $-1 \in P$ which means $(-1)\cdot (-1)=1 \in P$ and that is a contradiction.

So $1 \in P$ and $1+1 \in P$ and by induction $\mathbb N \subset P$. And for any $n\in \mathbb N$ then $-n \not \in P$.

Now we can figure if the number $\frac 1n; n\in \mathbb N$ is $P$ or not.  If $-\frac 1n\in P$ and $n\in P$ then $(-\frac 1n)\cdot n = -1 \in P$ and that's a contradiction so for all $n \in \mathbb N$ then $\frac 1n\in N$ and as all $m\in P$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$ then $m\cdot \frac 1n = \frac mn\in P$ and $\mathbb Q^+\subset P$.

And be induction we can prove all the positive algebraic irrational numbers are in $P$.... well, at least the even roots are.

I'm not actually sure there is a way to prove that all the positive irrational numbers are in $P$.  And maybe I can't.  Maybe there is a $P'$ that includes so negative irrational numbers.  But that doesn't actually matter.  We don't need to prove that $P$ is the only possible set; just that *one* such set exists.

And with the insight that $P$ must have all positive rational and probably all positive algebraic numbers, we can figure that $P$ could be $\mathbb R^+  = (0,\infty)$.

And $\mathbb R^+$ certainly works.  If $a,b\in (0,\infty)$ then $ab\in (0,\infty)$ and $a+b \in (0,\infty)$.  And if $x\in \mathbb R$ then 1) if $x \in (0,\infty)$, then $x\ne 0$ and $-x \not \in (0,\infty)$.  And 2) if $x=0$ then $x\not \in (0,\infty) $ and $-x \not \in (0,\infty)$.  And 3) is $x \not \in  (0,\infty)$ and $x \ne 0$ then $x\in(-\infty, 0)$ and $-x \in (0,\infty)$.

So $\mathbb R$ is an ordered field.

....

[Big picture:  we define $P$ and $\mathbb R^+$ and from there we are going to define what $a > b$ means which is $a > b$ if and only if $a-b \in P$.]

.....

Now why can't $\mathbb C$ be an ordered field?

Well we must decide if $i$ is $P$ or not.  If $i \in P$ then $i\cdot i = -1\in P$ but we already determined that if $-1\in P$ then $(-1)\cdot(-1)\in P$ and so both $1\in P$  and $-1\in P$ which is a contradiction. So we can't have $i\in P$.

And as $i\ne 0$ we must have $-i \in P$.  So $(-i)\cdot (-i)=-1\in P$.  A contradiction.  So neither $i$ nor $-i$ can be in $P$ which violates the definition of ordered field.

SO no such $P$ can exist.